# Tracing Native Calls

Tags: c++, winapi

This is Win32 related problem and all the code is native.

I have 3 layers compiled as dll libraries depending on each other:

[Module 1] -> [Module 2] -> [Module 3] -> [My Module 4]

Module 1 is an app loading Module 2. Module 2 loads Module 3. Module 3 loads My Module 4.

Whenever a call is made from Module 1 it goes through all layers up to module 4.

In Module 4 I would like to somehow trace that it's called by Module 3 from Module 2 from Module 1 by getting for example HMOUDLE handle for each of them or anything else uniquely identifying them. I can't think of any Win32 API allowing me to perform such a trace, can you advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) along with [SymFromAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the relevant address from the [STACKFRAME64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structures of interest. Not quite what you want but cannot think of any other way to get close.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - sort of, but you probably don't want to do this :)

Longish answer - The [Debug Help Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to generate a stack trace (via StackWalk64), which you could use in concert with module information retrieved via [PSAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get what you want.

The basic approach would be to obtain the base address and size of each module in your process, then have a look at the return addresses of each stack frame, matching by range.   If all you want to do is determine if a call to a function in module 4 originated from within module 1, this'll get you where you want to be.

Edit: If you've access to symbols to the modules in question, then Steve T's answer is a bit more robust.